# How to pass NULL to VARBINARY parameter in MSSQL pyodbc query

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc, freetds, varbinary

I am attempting to execute a stored procedure via a pyodbc cursor.

```
cursor.execute('EXEC MyProc ?', (None))
```

Where `MyProc` takes a `VARBINARY` parameter.

However, I get this error from FreeTDS:

```
pyodbc.DataError: ('22018', '[22018] [FreeTDS][SQL Server]Implicit conversion from data type varchar to varbinary is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query. (257) (SQLExecDirectW)')
```

Only other discussion of this issue I found on [this very old thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pyodbc/8yXi3bzk8EM).

Any ideas how to implement this?

My environment notes:

- Python code running on a Linux server
- Python 3.5
- pyodbc 3.0.10
- MS SQL Server 2014

Comment: Can you try `cursor.execute('EXEC MyProc @MyParam = ?', None)`? I've got a working example without a VARBINARY calling in that fashion.

Comment: I see that your error message refers to FreeTDS. Are you running this code on a non-Windows machine? FWIW, I am unable to reproduce your issue under Windows with `Driver={SQL Server Native Client 10.0}`.

Comment: @FlipperPA, No luck, unfortunately! Same error via: `cursor.execute('exec Test.dbo.spVarbinaryTest @Varbinary=?', None)`. FWIW, passing a valid byte string does work in the named parameter syntax too: `cursor.execute('exec Test.dbo.spVarbinaryTest @Varbinary=?', b'1234')`

Comment: @GordThompson indeed! Both syntaxes (named and unnamed params) work on Windows. I am running this on a linux server though. Tried on OSX and get the same error. Good tip though that this might be FreeTDS related -- I'll add that tag to the question.

Comment: @joeb1415 Can you include you freetds.conf, specifically which TDS version you are using?

Comment: FreeTDS version: `/usr/local/etc/freetds.conf -> ../Cellar/freetds/0.95.69/etc/freetds.conf`; On TDS version: `[global] tds version = 8.0`

Comment: I have the same exact error with python 2.7 and linux using FreeTDS. If I pass bytearray(0) from python, instead of None, it works. I want None (Null) though.